# jquery carousel - without a plugin

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am wanting to rotate my divs with next and prev buttons. I know there are plugins etc available, but I want to do it myself, only I am not too sure how.

So here is the html markup that I have so far

```
<div class="prev-btn"></div>
<div class="row"> <!-- content in here --></div>
<div class="row"> <!-- content in here --></div>
<div class="row"> <!-- content in here --></div>
<div class="next-btn"></div>
```

What I want to do is display 1 row at a time, and when I click on the prev/next button, display a different div. When I am on the last row, next will display the first row again.

I know how to do onclick events and toggle a div. But I really don't know how to determine which row I am on and how to select the next one to display.

How can I get my next/prev buttons to work correctly?

Comment: You want to do it yourself, but you're asking us how to do it. You can keep track of which one is active using an active class that you apply to the active slide. You can get the next or prev by using the jQuery .next() and .prev() methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an idea of how you can do this..

```
var $rotator = $(".container");
$rotator.find("div .row:gt(0)").hide();
```

get div you want to show and the next div in the list

```
var $current = $rotator.find("div .row:visible");
var $next = $current.next();
```

Now on click of next do this,

```
if ($next.length == 0) 
   $next = $rotator.find("div .row:eq(0)");

$current.hide();
$next.show();
```

Similarly you can use `.prev()` to get previous sibling div.

Here is a simple [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/LMw6F/310/)