# responsive html content carousel plugin or without

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm looking to make a responsive html content carousel. As shown on the image below.
[image: screen design]

Trying to use jQuery Cycle2, for this but couldn't achieve the effect I was looking for. Searching for a plugin that would be able to do this I figured that maybe the simplest solution would be to try to use plain JavaScript/jQuery.

Found this topic [jquery carousel - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752414/jquery-carousel-without-a-plugin)
Right now I'm struggling to achieve this with the responsive elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm not saying this has to be without a plugin just something that's not to hard to implement and maybe without too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use "bootstrap" : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You can achieve yr desired style by just writing..

```
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4> YOUR FIRST BOX HERE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4> YOUR SECOND BOX HERE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4>YOUR THIRD BOX HERE</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes but I want this to be a carousel not just responsive grid, that I have ready using bourbon, neat.